# If Value is true, create a new instance of an object

Tags: javascript, class, object, instantiation

Create new instance of an object based on an if statement result comparing user input value with a random value. I want it to create a new instance of an object if that is true and do that each time this comparison yields true.

**Would object.create() be the way to do this?**

```
 var firstthing = new thing();

 function createnewthing()
 {
    var entry = document.getElementById('theirentry').value;
    if (oneobjectinaclass == "type1")
    var firstvalueinarray = type1[0];
    else if (oneobjectinaclass == "type2")
    var firstvalueinarray = type2[0]; 
    else if (oneobjectinaclass == "type3")
    var firstvalueinanarray = type[0];
    if (variableassignedtowhichevertype[1] == avaluetocompare)
    {
        numCorrect++;
        alert('You\'re right! ' + numCorrect); 

        //the code I'm trying to get to accomplish this goes here
        //var createanotherthingeachtimethisistrue = new Thing();

    }
    else {
        alert('Wrong!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run your code? If you did, did that not work? What are you trying to accomplish (besides creating an object)?

Comment: It creates 1 object. I need for it to create a new one everytime the value passed is true. This runs many times. This would only create the createanotherthingeachtimethisistrue. The name was a placeholder to explain what it should do.

Comment: Can you put it in an array instead in that case? Your variable names are not descriptive of what you are really trying to accomplish. Creating a new object is as simple as typing `new Thing()`, but it's not clear if you've tried this and why in that case that is not a satisfactory behavior for you?

Comment: create an array with a for loop you're saying? I can create variables on the fly like that? var thing[i] ? Everytime a user inputs a value it verifies it through this function. I want it to create a new object when one is correct. Essentially restarting the thing to check.

Comment: well, no. Create an array `var arr = [];` and add items to that array, `arr.push(new Thing());`. Then again, I'm not sure if that's really what you want. If you want to "reset some items" then you should *assign* the first variable, not create a new local variable.

Comment: It's running math.random so it would need to run each time if I'm not mistaken. arr.push(new Thing()); looks like it would do it though.

Comment: Can you explain the context of the problem on a wider basis, I think it would be easier to help you out in that case? Otherwise, to answer your question as it stands, `var item = new Thing()` is a correct answer, but that doesn't help much.

Comment: In your example you should be able to just reassign the variable `scramble = cipher1.scramble(3, wordBase1.words());` ; Note the omission of `var` in the beginning. This means that you *assign* the previous variable instead of creating a new one

Comment: Could you word that in a pertinent manner for the above example. That worked for me, and I'd like to give you credit for a correct answer. Or whatever, I would like to credit you with solving my problem. 
firstthing = new thing();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises from the concept of Scope, which in JavaScript to put it simple is based on functions.

Therefore, in order to solve your problem you can assign a variable outside of the current scope by typing

```
value = new Thing();
```

Where value is a previously created variable in *some* functional context outside of the current function.

---

To dig deeper, we need to understand scopes in JavaScript. For more details, refer to [Scope (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) and for more insight into the matter, [Everything you wanted to know about JavaScript scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) by Todd Motto goes over it in more detail.

To put it short; A scope is "created" whenever we enter a function, and the environment frame of that scope is used whenever we create or access variables. If a variable is not available, the outer context (or environment frame) is used. So to put it in an example.

Example 1

```
var toy = 'stick';
function changeToy() {
   var toy = 'ball';
}
changeToy();
```

compared to Example 2

```
var toy = 'stick';
function changeToy() {
   toy = 'ball';
}
changeToy();
```

In Example 1 *a new* variable will be created and assigned because the environment frame is local to the function `changeToy`. In Example 2 the variable toy is not found in the environment frame for `changeToy`, so the outer context (the global context in this case) is used; in which the variable is found, and reassigned.